# `get_action_traces` listening for events will cause frame dropping in dfuse, solutions?

Tags: dfuse

Calling `get_action_traces` to listen for events will cause frame dropping. What should I do if I encounter this situation? Resend the listen request?

Comment: What do you mean by frame dropping?

Comment: I'm saying that I can receive the stream normally, but sometimes, when there are new transactions, I don't receive them

Comment: That would be very surprising. Come to our Telegram channel to debug your issue in detail. https://t.me/dfuseAPI